# Load effective address of a string in an array of strings?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, irvine32

Is there a way use `lea` on an array of pointers?

For example, we have an array of strings, is it possible to do a single line with `lea` instead of the two lines marked with `+`?

```
.data
ARR DWORD STR1, STR2 ...
STR1 byte "asdad", 0
...
.code
;;;lea edx, [ARR+4*eax]
mov edx, offset ARR   ;+
mov edx, [edx+4*eax]  ;+
call writestring
```

The commented out `lea` doesn't work and everything else I try doesn't even pass assembly.

Comment: Try `LEA ARR[edx+4*eax]. It should be `REG+SCALE*REG+disp32`.

Comment: @zx485 it doesn't work. Even with doing `mov edx, offset ARR` before `LEA ARR[edx+4*eax]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually want to use `LEA` since it calculates an address where you want the data contained in that address.

If you used `LEA` that would give you the address to location in the array. You can't use that in writing the string. Compared to C, for example, this would be the `char**` whereas you want `char*`.

If you want to write the string you have to do exactly as you're doing. You're actually reading the pointer contained in the array.

So in short, `LEA` is not what you want, you want the `MOV`s you are already using. You may be able to shorten it to one `MOV`:

```
mov edx, ARR[4*eax]
```

or with nasm

```
mov edx, [4*eax + ARR]
```

Comment: `offset` means address of symbol. So `[offset ARR]` is basically equal to shorter `[ARR]`, while `offset [ARR]` doesn't make much sense - this is sort of what `lea` does, but it doesn't call it offset, the "ea" in `lea` means "effective address". `offset` is used usually when some ambiguity may happen, like some assemblers treat `mov eax,ARR` as loading eax with ARR address, and some as loading eax with value at ARR address. I avoid that syntax completely, and either use `mov eax, offset ARR`, or `mov eax,[ARR]` depending what I want to load.